# Как нужно указать тип столбца, чтобы при вставке создавалось время в заданном формате?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Как нужно указать тип столбца в таблице, чтобы при вставке создавалось время  такого формата -- `17:50:09.0`?

Таблица – Edit – Columns – Type (Что тут нужно выбрать?)

Или для значенния по умолчанию - Default, что нужно указать, чтобы был только формат времени - `17:50:09.0`?.

Comment: Не путайте формат хранения данных (и сервер не будет в принципе слушать чьих-то пожеланий в этом вопросе) и формат отображения этих данных у клиента (а вот тут рулите им как хотите - благо на это имеются соответствующие форматирующие функции).

Comment: Т.е. в default столбца я могу поставить только sysdate? Только время не вывести?

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Вы имеете в виду, что поле имеет тип даты-времени, и что при вставке любого значения следует "отрезать" компоненту времени и подставить вместо неё указанное значение?

Comment: Да, мне нужно только время, отсечь дату

Comment: В Oracle емнип нет типа данных TIME.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Формат хранения даты и времени изменить невозможно (см. ниже).

Если нужен символьный формат колонки содержащий только время, то создайте колонку для хранения даты/времени `DATE` и дополнительно к ней виртуальную колонку.

Например (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=060854f044c1057ee2742b61b6a04df6)):

```
create table t (
    id int, dt date default sysdate, 
    time char(10) as (to_char (dt, 'hh24:mi:ss".0"')))
/
insert into t (id) values(1);
```

Формат значений, полученных из виртуальной колонки известен заранее и не зависит от каких-либо настроек:

```
select id, time from t;

        ID TIME      
---------- ----------
         1 11:22:33.0
```

---

Формат хранения даты и времени выглядит так:

```
DUMP(DT,16)
---------------------------------
Typ=12 Len=7: 78,79,6,17,17,23,22
```

И изменить его могут только разработчики Oracle.

Если при поиске будет найдено решение, предлагающее хранить дату или время как символьную строку, то оно заведомо неверно.

Comment: Если при создании ругается на as (to_char (dt, 'hh24:mi:ss'))  ora-12899:значение для столбца "TIME" слишком велико(факт.8 макс.75)

Comment: @wq55 [на фиддле](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ba4a942260367f711fc102daa6899ede)